# How much memory and storage does a website take on a server?

Tags: 8

Hello Drupal community!

This is my first time working with Drupal and AWS. I would like to know if an AWS t2.micro instance would be good enough for running a new Drupal 8 website with moderate requirements. My main goal with this is to stay within the [AWS free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/), i.e, spend no money for one year whatsoever. The [EC2 information page](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) states that a t2.micro instance has 1GB of memory and "EBS only" storage (bear in mind that this is the storage for the *server*). After looking into this I found that EBS has 30GB's of storage. Will that much be sufficient?

Totally I have to run a Drupal 8 site, an AWS RDS MySQL database and AWS S3, all on this instance comfortably (which obviously means a good amount of people should be able to view the website  at the same time too). Any requirements for Drupal 8 would be welcomed.

Please get me out of this jam. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Im afraid hardware/hosting recommendations are something we specifically don't do here, as there's no way to give you a real answer without knowing how your site will be used, what modules you'll have installed, how they'll be configured, how much traffic you're getting over what period of time, and so on. The best advice anyone can give is to benchmark your site under various conditions (eg using Apache ab), and make an informed decision that way

Comment: Thank you @Clive! I love this community! I am quite a noob at this, but I'll try my best to answer you. 1) I didn't get what you meant by saying "how your site will be used" 2) Give me a while to research about these modules please 3) I think you have mistaken that I already have this site up and running somewhere. I don't. So, I cannot say what the traffic is going to be (A fair assumption would be a 1500 people per month at first). Now about your advice- I can't benchmark as I don't already have this site up. I know I haven't been very helpful but that is the knowledge I have as of now.

Comment: That's understandable, bit I'm afraid it doesn't change what's on or off topic on this site. Q+A is for questions that have an objective answer; there isn't a way to answer this without knowing all of the parameters, and even if we had those, it would be so tied down to your specific use case as not to be useful to future visitors. See http://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning on server fault for a good explanation of why we can't help with this type of query here

Comment: I believe the answer is "no". I tried to use the AWS free tier for Drupal 7. It ran out of the box, but hit the ceiling after I added just a few modules. I haven't tried this with Drupal 8, but I think Drupal 8, but a heavier load in the server, so I don't think it will be usable.

Comment: @FreeRadical thanks for your response! It is really helpful and straight to the point! I really appreciate your answer even though I am a bit frustrated to know that it doesn't work for free :P

Comment: @Clive I didn't mean to come across like I was trying to put the question off hold. Sorry if I did that.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine with 1GB server ram, and 256M set for PHP. Keep in mind you won't be running a huge site with it, so also invest in getting caching like memcache and something like varnish going as well. I'm not sure if memcache is PHP7 ready yet - but using php7 will gain some performance increase as well.

However if you're looking for free hosting, I think you could also try Acquia Cloud Free.

Comment: Hi Kevin! I tried acquia cloud free, but they wanted cash just so I could use a custom domain. Oh well. Thanks for the suggestion though! Now a few questions I had. How will caching help? And when you said "and 256M set for PHP", did that mean 256MB on the same server or on a different one? Thanks!